# Define the visual property for an object that extends FrameworkElement in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

This is a rather simple question:

I want to build an object in windows phone that extends the frameworkElement class.

```
public class ObjectName: FrameworkElement
       {
            public Image image {get; set;}
```

This class should have a visual property, for example and Image. The question is: How can I define that everytime I refer to this Object in a visual manner, I am actually referring to the Image property? For example:

```
Canvas.SetTop(ObjectName, h * height);
Canvas.SetLeft(ObjectName, w * width);

PictureBoard.Children.Add(ObjectName); // PictureBoard is a Canvas element
```

Rather than

```
Canvas.SetTop(ObjectName.image, h * height);
Canvas.SetLeft(ObjectName.image, w * width);

PictureBoard.Children.Add(ObjectName.image); // PictureBoard is a Canvas element
```

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do exactly, so it's just an idea: Wouldn't it be easier to use the `Image` class or inherit from it as `Image` is inherited from `FrameworkElement`?

You could possibly do something like that:

```
public class SpecialImage : Image
{
    // if you want to add custom logic, do it :)
}

SpecialImage specialImage = new SpecialImage();
Canvas.SetTop(specialImage, h * height);
Canvas.SetLeft(specialImahe, w * width);
PictureBoard.Children.Add(specialImage);
```

As I'm writing this, I think, you don't just use Images but also other visual elements? If so, this wouldn't be a solution.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not directly answer my question. It may solve my problems though, still, I would appreciate to know if there exists a direct way to define the visual property, sth like the DataContext is what I have in mind.